# OSError: [WinError 87]The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python

I am learning distributed process on an python tutorial website  : https://www.liaoxuefeng.com/wiki/0014316089557264a6b348958f449949df42a6d3a2e542c000/001431929340191970154d52b9d484b88a7b343708fcc60000#0

Here is the turorial code that run as a main process.

## task_master.py

```
import random, time, queue
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager


task_queue = queue.Queue()
result_queue = queue.Queue()

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass
    
QueueManager.register('get_task_queue', callable=lambda:task_queue)
QueueManager.register('get_result_queue', callable=lambda:result_queue)
manager = QueueManager(address=('',5000), authkey=b'abc')
manager.start()
task = manager.get_task_queue()
result = manager.get_result_queue()
for i in range(10):
    n = random.randint(0,10000)
    print('Put task %d...' %n)
    task.put(n)
print('Try get result...')
for i in range(10):
    r = result.get(timeout = 10)
    print('Result:%s'%r)
manager.shutdown()
print('master exit.')
```

The code is not completed, for it raises some errors that I have no idea how to deal with when I tied to run it on my computer.

## error

```
D:\py>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Raven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\Raven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect。
```

Answer (score 0):

multiprocessing in windows is different than linux - specifically, windows uses `spawn` while linux uses `fork` (well, there's more to it, but that's a summary).

The tutorial you're following is written on linux according to the prompts, while you're on windows. You can tell `multiprocessing` to use `spawn` instead of `fork` by something like this:

```
import random, time, queue
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')

from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  
I tried replace my 'import' code with your 'import' code.  
It did'nt work 
C:\Users\xiangmu003\py>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xiangmu003\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\xiangmu003\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87]

Comment: Same here: I added `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` to code that works in `macOS` and got the same error.