# Problem with Filedialog in Python, Selenium 'NameError'

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, web-scraping, openfiledialog

I work on this Projekt where I try to get Links from a Website and I got it to work after 2-3 Weeks and now my Task is to build an GUI with TKinter. The Problem is that I ask the User to select the Driver that is needed for the Selenium Operation, that grabs the Links from the Website

So this is my Code and probably the Problem is easy but I'm just stuck at the part from coderetter() to code() where I give the Filepath to the Driver it always says: "NameError: name 'save' is not defined" and I tried everything
The Problem occurs on the last line by executable_path that where i want to let the User choose the path.

Has anyone got any similar kind of problem or does someone maybe see the problem here?

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from multiprocessing import Process

def Fenster():

    root = Tk()
    root.title("MS-Search Grabber")
    w = Label(root, text='W!')

    driverButt = Button(text='Chrome-Driver', command=coderetter)
    FileSave = Button(text='Save CSV', command=saveFile)
    StartB = Button(text='Start Process', command=proSt)
    w.pack()
    driverButt.pack()
    FileSave.pack()
    StartB.pack()
    root.mainloop()

def coderetter():

    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()



def saveFile():

    save = filedialog.asksaveasfile()
    return save

def proSt():
    p2 = Process(target=code)
    p2.start()


def code():

    why = saveFile(save)
    
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    chrome_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=why, options=chrome_options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = ''
    driver= ''
    save = ''
    p1 = Process(target=Fenster)
    p1.start()
```

Comment: Try changing `coderetter()` to have a `global file` and `saveFile()` to have a `global save`.

Comment: Thanks but how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The use of `global` will enable file and save strings to be available to other parts of your code.
By using global in saveFile, you do not need a return
This means Filesave button will also function correctly since buttons do not accept returned information.

```py
def coderetter():
    global file
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def saveFile():
    global save
    save = filedialog.asksaveasfile()

def proSt():
    p2 = Process(target=code)
    p2.start()

def code():
    saveFile()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you describe any errors or behavior that might help?

Comment: OSError: [WinError 87] Wrong Parameter, is the Problem that i get after selecting my file through askopenfilename

Comment: Here is a link that might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627793/oserror-winerror-87the-parameter-is-incorrect